# Alternative form of the Integral of Gaussian function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Integral_of_a_Gaussian_function), there is an alternative form of the integral of the Gaussian function, which is
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k\exp\left(-fx^2 + gx + h \right)dx
&=\int k\exp\left( (-f(x-g/(2f))^2 + g^2/(4f) + h\right)dx \\
&= k\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{f}}\exp\left(\frac{g^2}{4f}+h\right)
\end{align}$$
For the case where $gx+h=0$, this can be solved using polar coordinates. For $h=0$, I can complete the square. For the case where neither are zero, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Can you not also complete the square if $h \neq 0$?

Comment: $e^{\frac {g^{2}} {4f}+h}$ is a constant. Pull it out and make the substitution $y=x-\frac g {2f}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, i did not notice that right away.